# How to simulate adding new device (USB)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, virtual-machine, devices

I am trying to test the behavior of license after added new device (USB) in virtual machine. Are there any commands for simulating that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “behavior of license”. Apart from that, Qemu supports emulation of USB devices: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB

Comment: Behavior of internal license of company. If customer will be able to use old license after added new device to pc or customer have to generate new one.

Comment: I'm still not getting the question.  Do you mean a usb license key?  Licensed material or program on a usb drive?  Do you just need to add a usb device to some kind of virtual machine and see what happens?